# Findbugs issue with "Boxing/unboxing to parse a primitive" with Integer.valueOf(String)

Tags: java, findbugs, boxing, unboxing

I have this piece of code:

```
public void someMethod(String id) {
   someOtherMethod(Integer.valueOf(id));
}

public void someOtherMethod(int id) {
   // do something with id
}
```

And on that second line, Findbugs is throwing this exception:

> Boxing/unboxing to parse a primitive

Why is Findbugs complaining about this when I'm simply calling Integer.valueOf() / how can I fix this?

Answer (score 70):

The issue is that [`Integer.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) returns an `Integer`, not an `int`, but your `someOtherMethod` expects an `int`. Findbugs is basically warning you that you're doing it a long-winded way that involves potentially creating an object (the `Integer`) that you don't need which you're then immediately going to unbox by passing it to `someOtherMethod(int)`, e.g.:

```
String => int => Integer => int
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                \--- This is inside Integer.valueOf
```

Instead, you can and probably should avoid that unnecessary round-trip through `Integer` and simply do:

```
String => int
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      \--- Integer.parseInt
```

There's just no need for the temporary `Integer` and the potential memory allocation and such surrounding it.

If `someOtherMethod` were expecting an `Integer`, you wouldn't get the warning, because the `Integer` isn't purely temporary.

This is just one of a class of unnecessary-boxing-conversions that Findbugs and tools like it helpfully point out.

Answer (score 22):

It took me a while to figure that one out (partially because Jenkins just said "Boxing/unboxing to parse a primitive"), but apparently the problem / solution is in what Integer.valueOf() does internally, namely:

```
Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s, 10));
```

So the solution is to simply to call parseInt() directly instead:

```
someOtherMethod(Integer.parseInt(id));
```

The detailed description of the issue (DM_BOXED_PRIMITIVE_FOR_PARSING) can be found on the [findbugs page](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DM_BOXED_PRIMITIVE_FOR_PARSING).

Comment: *"but apparently the problem / solution is in what Integer.valueOf() does internally"* That's not the *problem*, no. It does carry the seeds of the solution, but it's not the problem.

Comment: Em ... your solution is exactly what I said (first) ... namely to use Integer.parseInt() directly instead of Integer.valueOf() that causes the boxing/unboxing to happen. You just used more words to explain it.

Comment: The difference is that I *did* explain it. The above just says "use `parseInt`" without an explanation of *why* Findbugs is pointing out an issue.

Comment: FindBugs [does point that out](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DM_BOXED_PRIMITIVE_FOR_PARSING): "A boxed primitive is created from a String, just to extract the unboxed primitive value. It is more efficient to just call the static parseXXX method". If you have better idea how to formulate it, pull-requests [are welcome](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/pulls).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - This isn't an issue about explaining boxing/unboxing, this is an issue about how to solve that particular problem. I still think you simply took my answer and beefed it up with somewhat unrelevant information (to the question anyway).

Comment: @TagirValeev - Hmmm ... you're right, more information can be found if you dig a bit more, but all my Jenkins build pointed out is: 
[INFO] BugInstance size is 1
[INFO] Error size is 0
[INFO] Total bugs: 1
[INFO] Boxing/unboxing to parse a primitive

Comment: @mac: Then you don't know me very well. And I don't think you've really *read* the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yup, you're right, I don't know you at all. ;) And, yes, I did read your answer. Anyhow ...

Comment: I have updated my answer with the feedback from @TagirValeev (thanks!). I'm guessing that's more than plenty of info (from the two answers) to know how to resolve the issue when you come across it. In the future, I would suggest TagirValeev's approach: Provide comments to make an answer better ...